# oracle adf runtime UI generation

Tags: jsf-2, oracle11g, oracle-adf

I am working on oracle adf with bounded taskflow and generating the ui dynamically on run time but the problem is that the UI components are not clickable and I am unable to click on the ui components, the code is as follows.

```
public String testMethod() {
    // Add event code here...

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UIViewRoot root = facesContext.getViewRoot();


    RichPanelGroupLayout panelGrpLayout = new RichPanelGroupLayout();
    panelGrpLayout.setId( "pgl1" );
    panelGrpLayout.setLayout( "scroll" );

    RichMenuBar menuBar = new RichMenuBar();
    menuBar.setId( "rmb1" );
    menuBar.setVisible( true );

    panelGrpLayout.getChildren().add( menuBar );

    RichCommandButton button = new RichCommandButton();

    button.setId( "cmi1" );
    button.setVisible( true );
    button.setText( "First" );
    button.setPartialSubmit( true );
    button.setRendered( true );

    String method = "#{backingBeanScope.CLBean.testMethod}";
    Application app = facesContext.getApplication();
    ExpressionFactory elFactory = app.getExpressionFactory();
    ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
    MethodExpression methExp = elFactory.createMethodExpression(elContext, method, Object.class, new Class[0]);

    button.addActionListener( new MethodExpressionActionListener(methExp) );


    root.addComponentResource( facesContext, button );

    return "product";

}
```

The UI components showed up properly but they are not clickable any help will be highly appreciated.Thanks

Regards,
Furqan Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

Adding components dynamically is fragile in ADF/JSF. You have to be mindful of the JSF lifecycle and the 'correct' time to create new components (that is, after the viewstate has been restored from the previous request, but before any new viewstate is serialized).

I have liased with both the MyFaces and the Mojarra teams at length to determine the 'correct' approach (as agreed by all parties) and documented it here:

http://blog.kennardconsulting.com/2010/10/safely-manipulating-component-tree-with.html

This is also implemented in my Open Source library Metawidget (http://metawidget.org), to save you the hard work :)